# What are co-products for directed graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

I define a digraph as a set $V$ (vertexes) and a relation $E$ (edges) on $V$.

Morphisms of digraph are functions which preserve $E$.

So we have a category.

What are co-products in this category? (I am especially interested what are the canonical injections.)

Comment: Coproducts are disjoint unions: you can check this by hand.

Comment: Zhen means that $\coprod_i (V_i,E_i) = (\coprod_i V_i,\coprod_i E_i)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: I don't really care (especially since porton hasn't answered).